# Why can't I directly access the object used in the let scope function instead of it in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I know that the *Code C* is the same as the *Code A*.

I hope to use the variable `aa` instead of `it` in *Code B*, but it cause error.

Why isn't the *Code B* same as the *Code A*?

**Code A**

```
private var aa:String?=null 

aa?.let{
       print(it.length)
}
```

**Code B**

```
private var aa:String?=null 

aa?.let{
        print(aa.length)
}
```

**Code C**

```
private var aa:String?=null 

aa?.let{
       aa-> print(aa.length)
}
```

Comment: What you've done is reassign the implicit parameter name (it) to an explicit parameter name (aa).

Comment: What's the error? I've just run it with no problems with Kotlin 1.3.50. The error in your code is using private with a local variable

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`it` is just the name kotlin gives to a parameter implicitly, which you can override with your own name (which happens in C where the parameter name is set to `aa`).

In A, you use `it` as an implicit parameter, where it refers to a value equivalent to `aa` after it has gone through a null check.

B doesn't work because unlike in C and A, `aa` refers to the `var` you declared outside of your `let`, which is nullable. As it is nullable, you can't simply call `length` on it in the same way as in A and C.

Comment: What OP has done in C is *shadow* the `aa` var with the `aa` val in the lambda scope. Not usually considered good practice.

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR

Yes you can use `aa` inside `T.let` function but the problem is that it won't be casted to your object, so either or you cast it manually or you won't be able to use methods of your variable type.

---

I recommend you to read this [it implicit name of a single parameter](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html?_ga=2.268416779.48780587.1573548884-1310030218.1571915784#it-implicit-name-of-a-single-parameter) to better understanding of `it`.

@PPartisan explained it ok, the thing is that yes, you can use `aa` inside your `T.let` function the problem that you are having is that the compiler is trying to do a smart cast to `String` and it's impossible to do that because `aa` is a mutable property that could have been changed.

If you try to add another function like `isNullOrBlank()` it will not complain.

Also one point is, `T.let` function is checking for nullability and if `aa` is null it won't do whatever is inside even if you put `it` or `aa` so an example could be :

```
private var aa:String?=null

fun main() {
    println("Hello, world!!!")
    aa = "pewlas"
    aa?.let{
        print("example"+aa.orEmpty())
    }
}
```

output :

> Hello, world!!!
>
> examplepewlas

When you use `it` it will cast it to a `String` so, if you use `aa` inside the `T.let` function it won't cast it to String and then you won't be able to use methods from `String` like you are trying to do with `lenght` function.